# Processing bunch of URL's with CURL

Tags: php, curl, parallel-processing

I'm working on a project that has to move/write a bunch of files (hundreds of them). Right now they're done one after another, so I'm going to be doing it in parallel to speed up the process.

The biggest work is done, using a modified version of the PHP class found here: http://semlabs.co.uk/journal/object-oriented-curl-class-with-multi-threading

Right now I can add 100 url's and then tell the script to parse 10 urls in parallel. This 
however means I have to wait until the first 10 are done, to do the next 10.

I was wondering if there was a way to set it up like a queue? Start with 10, then as soon as the first one is done (the one out of those 10 that is done first), move on to number 11, etc ...

Is there any way to do this in PHP? (doesn't *have* to be with CURL). Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

One possible option is using CRON jobs.

Another is Zend_Queue, but I think its requirement is Zend Server. I'm not sure, though.

Answer (score 0):

Your script may generate a "processing request token" (DB or filesystem based) that would be processed by background daemons. Each daemon starts by "eating" the token then process stuff, if each daemon can process 10 urls just start 10 daemons to process 100 urls at a time ...

Answer (score 0):

Do you have access to the server that your site is hosted? ie. do you have the ability to setup cron jobs / your own program's (ie. running php from the console)?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a job for [Gearman](http://www.php.net/gearman). You'd submit each list of 10 urls as a job, and have a number of workers running which pick up the jobs as soon as they're available. The advantage of this is you can trivially improve the parallelism later by starting up more workers (even on different machines).